# On existence of eigen bases

Tags: linear-algebra

Given an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ and an operator $T$ on $V$ is there a necessary and sufficient condition on $T$ for it to have an eigen basis?

I know a sufficient condition:  if $T$ has $n$ different eigen values then the corresponding vectors are all linearly independent. And $T$ has $n$ different eigenvalues if and only if its characteristic polynomial has n different roots.

Are there any necessary conditions so that one could say if $T$ does not dsatisfy porperty $P$ then it can't have $n$ different eigenvalues?

Answer (score 1):

I find the quickest method to check, whether a transformation $T$ (or matrix $A$) has a basis of eigenvectors is the following: $T$ has a basis of eigenvectors $\Longleftrightarrow m_T(x)$ is a product of distinct linear factors, where $m_T(x)$ denotes the minimal polynomial of $T$. In general the minimal polynomial is difficult to compute, but we can use the following two Lemma's:

**Lemma 1:** $m_T(x)\mid \chi _T(x)$, where $\chi _T(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial.
This follows from the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

**Lemma 2:** Every linear factor of $\chi _T(x)$ is a factor of $m_T(x)$.
*Proof*: The linear factors of $\chi _T(x)$ are precisely the ones of the form $x-\lambda$ with $\lambda$ an eigenvalue of $T$. So let $v$ be an eigenvector of $T$ w.r.t. $\lambda$ (this means $v\neq 0$), then $$0=m_T(T)v=m_T(\lambda )v.$$Thus, $m_T(\lambda )=0$, because $v\neq 0$, and $x-\lambda$ is a linear factor of $m_T(x)$ q.e.d.

So we get the condition: Let $\chi _T(x)=\prod_{i=1}^m(x-\lambda _i)^{m_i}$ (if the characteristic polynomial is not a product of linear factors, then $T$ cannot possibly have a basis of eigenvectors), and put $p(x)=\prod_{i=1}^m(x-\lambda _i)$. Note that by Lemma 2, $p(x)\mid m_T(x)$. If $p(T)\neq 0$, then $m_T(x)\neq p(x)$, so by Lemma 1 $m_T(x)$ is  not a product of distinct linear factors. Conversely, if $p(T)=0$, then $m_T(x)\mid p(x)$, thus $m_T(x)=p(x)$ is a product of distinct linear factors.

Therefore, we do not need the minimal polynomial explicitly to know whether $T$ has a basis of eigenvectors, it suffices to compute the characteristic polynomial and then check for the corresponding $p(x)$ whether $p(T)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a basis of eigenvectors for $T$ if and only if the characteristic polynomial of $T$ splits and for each eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $T$, the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$ is equal to the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda$.

(This is the "test for diagonalization" given in section 5.2 of [Linear Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0130084514) by Friedberg, Insel, and Spence.)

Answer (score 1):

If you confine yourself by  finite-dimensional real or complex spaces then  an linear operator is diagonalizable (by an unitary matrix) if and only if it is normal
(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem).

Comment: @ littleO Yes, thank you. I correected the answer.